# Meaning of “that was for six units of a credit”

Tags: expressions

This sentence is from the class of MIT finance and I’m confused what does the following sentence means (see pic for full context)
“that was for six units of a credit”

[image]

Comment: Can you post the audio? I suspect this is a captioning error, and that he really said "units of credit" (no article). Credit units here refers to [academic course credits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_credit).

Comment: I found the video [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wvXDB9dMdEo). For future reference, "full context" should include a link to the source, when available; not just a screen capture of YouTube.

Answer (score 3):

Courses at MIT and elsewhere carry a certain number of *credits* toward graduation. Three credit courses are common at most schools. MIT uses a different system:

> Credit units for MIT subjects are defined by three numbers: hours per
> week of lecture or recitation, hours per week of lab or field work,
> and hours per week of outside preparation. ... Faculty policy defines
> a single unit as approximately one hour of effort per week, or 14
> hours per term, for a typical full-term subject.

From
https://registrar.mit.edu/faculty-curriculum-support/curriculum-schedule-planning/proposing-subject/calculating-instructional

Comment: The video is here: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wvXDB9dMdEo the speaker (who is not a native English speaker and has a Chinese accent) does say "six units of credit" (no article, but there is an inflection here due to his accent). Later he says this 2nd run of the class is for 12 credits. MIT must measure credits differently than what you and I had in college.

Comment: @TypeIA See my edit.

Comment: @TypeIA Sounds like MIT is using the system of course credits that a lot of Australian universities also use. Not sure where it originally came from.